# How to prevent from automatic reboot after shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have a problem with shutting down my systems. When I shutdown my laptop everything looks normal but after few seconds it powers on by itself. I tried to shut it down through terminal with "shutdown -h now" and it worked but only on Arch in Ubuntu with "shutdown -hH now" or "shutdown -H now" it hangs on spash screen. I also looked for some "wake on LAN" BIOS entries (as those are mentioned to cause that problem) but I don't have those.

How can I fix my distros to be able to shutdown distros form DE's menu without using terminal ?

Comment: That's typically a problem with ACPI tables. What exact model of laptop do you have? What kernels do you run on the working distribution and on the non-working one?

Comment: It's kind of strange because it looks like shutdown works fine while the power cord in connected but on battery not so much. So what didn't fix it was [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1002429) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown/135568#135568) and what did (at least for the moment) was removing from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= something like this: "quiet resume=UUID=6gwe72ic-3alp..." (I've overriten grub file so I can't quote it exactly) and simply replaced it with "quiet splash"...

Comment: @banuy You broke hibernation and didn't even fix your problem really. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

On your hardware, it is possible that this is not supported via an OS interface.  THus when you shutdown it reboots.  I have run into this many times.

BTW, have you tried 'init 0' instead of shutdown?

The other thing I'd be looking is a BIOS option addressing this.  All the BIOS makers are a little different, so I cannot provide a canned answer.

Comment: depending on distro, you might have to use telinit 0 instead of init 0.

Comment: `init 0` does the same thing as `shutdown -h now`.

Answer (score 0):

Some Intel Ivy Bridge and Haswell chipsets included an XHCI USB3 controller version that needs to be shut down in a *very specific way*, or else it will just power on the system again after a few seconds.

The trouble is, the *specific way* is different for different versions of the chipsets, and the shutdown procedure that fixes the problem for one chipset version will actually *cause* it for another version.

Because the system firmware will in most cases start up the XHCI controller to probe for USB keyboards and mice, blacklisting the `xhci_hcd` driver will not help in this cause, and might in fact make the problem worse.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171

If you have this problem and a system with a chipset of this era, you might try adding one of these kernel module options to `/etc/modprobe.d/xhci.conf`:

```
options xhci-hcd quirks=270336 

options xhci-hcd quirks=8192

options xhci-hcd quirks=262144
```

**Try just one of these lines at a time.** The correct `quirks` value will depend on the exact chipset version your system has.